# How to uninstall graphics.h from ubuntu?

Tags: c, ubuntu, debian, dpkg, bgi

I have installed `graphics.h` using the following steps:

1. First install `build-essential` by typing

   ```
   sudo apt-get install build-essential
   ```
2. Install some additional packages by typing

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libsdl-image1.2 libsdl-image1.2-dev guile-2.0 \
     guile-2.0-dev libsdl1.2debian libart-2.0-dev libaudiofile-dev \
     libesd0-dev libdirectfb-dev libdirectfb-extra libfreetype6-dev \
     libxext-dev x11proto-xext-dev libfreetype6 libaa1 libaa1-dev \
     libslang2-dev libasound2 libasound2-dev
   ```
3. Now extract the downloaded `libgraph-1.0.2.tar.gz` file.
4. Go to the folder where the files were extracted and run the following commands:

   ```
   ./configure
   make
   sudo make install
   sudo cp /usr/local/lib/libgraph.* /usr/lib
   ```

But now how do I uninstall it again?

Comment: Why do you want to only uninstall that specific header? `dpkg -S /usr/lib/include/graphics.h` will reveal which exact package provides it (provided this is the correct path).

Comment: Try `sudo make uninstall`

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/87111/if-i-build-a-package-from-source-how-can-i-uninstall-or-remove-completely

Comment: Note: you should never do your last step. `/usr/local` is the correct place (and it is expected that program recognize such places), and so you should keep file there. Leave /usr/lib to packages (so with easy way to remove, and to track the origin)